# Dropbox-like client for WebDav

Tags: macos, windows-7, webdav

[Not so much programming related as sysadmining related, but maybe someone can help me out]

My office started using a centralised file repository that is accessible via WebDav. Some users are spoiled with dropbox and ask me questions like 'so why does it take forever to change directory on this shared drive' and the like. Both OSX and Win7 users complain that this webdav mount is nowhere near as seamless as dropbox is. My question: Can anyone recommend a webdav client / sync tool that could do the synchronization in the background and not at access time?

I am aware of dropDAV, but that provides webdav access to dropbox folders which is the opposite of what I want.

Comment: This question is better suits [su] or [sf].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [SMEStorage](http://smestorage.com). We are using them with Amazon S3 and WebDav. We're using the Linux and Mac clients (although they do support Windoze also) and their iOS and WP7 clients.

Comment: thank you, this is exactly what I was after. Not as lean as dropbox, but a lot more versatile and a lot lot lot better than naked webdav.